# Peut-on dire "plié en" indépendamment du processus ?

Tags: expressions, dictionnaires

A/ Je prends une feuille de papier que :

- a.1 / Je plie en deux
- a.2 / Je replie une seconde fois en deux

J'obtiens fort logiquement une feuille *pliée en quatre*.

B/ Je prends une autre feuille de papier que :

- b.1 / Je plie en deux
- b.2 / Je découpe en deux suivant le pli,
- b.3 / Je plie chacun des deux morceaux en deux.

Puis-je toujours dire que j'ai une feuille *pliée en quatre* ?

Je dirais bien que non sauf que voici la définition que donnent les dictionnaires pour *in-dix-huit* :

- *la feuille d'impression est pliée en dix-huit feuillets et forme un cahier de trente-six pages* pour le [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/in-dix-huit)
- *la feuille d’impression est pliée en dix-huit feuillets* pour [Académie 9](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/in-dix-huit)

Quand on sait qu'à un moment donné du [processus](https://www.moulinduverger.com/reliure-manuelle/roret-14.php), il y aura découpe puis pliage séparé des deux parties, (Nécessairement puisque 18 n'est pas une puissance de 2), je m'interroge.

---

<sup>NDaCOSwt : J'ai déjà posé cette question ailleurs sur le net, mais la discussion s'est développée sur un autre sujet.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Il paraît clair que le processus B donne deux feuilles pliées en deux, et non une feuille pliée en quatre.

Comme indiqué dans une autre réponse, il est tout à fait possible de plier une feuille en 18, il suffit de la plier en six dans une direction et en trois dans une autre.

Comment: C'est effectivement ce constat très rationnel que tu fais dans ton premier paragraphe qui a motivé ma question. Or, oui, malgré le fait qu'il soit possible de plier une feuille en 18 sans découpe, il se trouve que, dans le processus de fabrication d'un in-18 tel qu'exposé dans le lien fourni dans l'OP, la page subit une découpe entre les différentes opération de pliage.

Comment: Le plus simple n'est-il pas de supposer que ni le TLF ni l'Académie n'ont examiné le processus pratique de fabrication d'un in-18 au moment d'élaborer leurs définitions ?

Answer (score 0):

En utilisant la technique des cartes, [*le pliage accordéon*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pliure#/media/Fichier:Pliaccordeon.png), on peut avoir un nombre pair (ou multiple de trois) important de feuillets.

> — 8 plis parallèles et 1 transversal : … ***plié en** 18 feuillets*.
>
> — 5 plis parallèles et 2 transversaux : … ***plié en** 18 feuillets*.

---

***Complément** suite au commentaire d’aCOSwt*

*Plier* s’emploie avec *en* :

> — suivi d’un nombre : une feuille ***pliée en*** seize a donné quatre feuillets séparés (égaux ou avec un nombre différent de pages).

La découpe intermédiaire ne change rien, on peut le préciser par la suite ; même sans cette coupe intermédiaire, à la fin, il faudra découper les pages du livre.

> — suivi du résultat de l’action de plier un objet : une feuille *prédécoupée **pliée en** forme de* cube.

Une feuille pliée une fois :

> — Si l’on coupe en suivant la ligne de la pliure, on sépare une feuille en deux, cela donne deux feuilles sans pliure.
>
> — si l’on coupe la ligne de la pliure, cela donne deux feuillets de deux pages, le feuillet étant le résultat d’une feuille pliée.

Comment: Merci pour ta réponse cl-r et pour l'information sur la technique de pliage. Néanmoins, ma question ne porte pas formellement sur la possibilité ou non de plier en 18 sans découpe. Mais bien plutôt, **dans la certitude qu' il y a découpe intérmédiaire** (cf lien donné dans l'OP sur processus), peut-on toujours dire *plié en*.